# asp.net autocomplete combobox functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, autocomplete

Does asp ajaxtoolkit autocomplete combobox have some javascript functions available, so we could select selecteditem text or selected item value in client side.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean this, here you can download the complete source code with all js files:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Otherwise, here is a short documentation:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

I think, you can control this behaviour through the completion service method, where is up to you, how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoComplete1_OnClientShown(sender, eventArgs) {
        var valueToSelect = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID  %>").val();

        if (valueToSelect.length > 0) {
            var itemToSelect = $("li[_value^='" + valueToSelect + "']", ".CompletionList").get(0);
            Sys.Debug.traceDump(itemToSelect);
            if (itemToSelect)
                $find("AutoCompleteEx")._setText(itemToSelect);
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1" Text="Select the first value that starts with: " />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />&nbsp;
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox2" Text="Choose value: " />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" />
    <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server"
            BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
            ID="autoComplete1" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox2"
            ServicePath="Default.aspx" 
            ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
            DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
            CompletionListCssClass="CompletionList"
            OnClientShown="autoComplete1_OnClientShown"
            ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="false" >
     </ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
```